# React-Native: Unexplainable space(a white line) between two Views

Tags: android, react-native

I have two Views stacked one on top the other.

Screenshot in emulator:

[image: :]

What I see on my phone:
[image]

As can be seen from the screens, the emulator version is fine but i have a **white line between the two Views** on my phone. Code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

class FlightSearch extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.pageRoot}>

        <View style={styles.navSection}></View>

        <View style={styles.searchSection}>

          <View style={styles.locationSection}></View>

          <View style={styles.searchParametersSection}></View>

        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }

}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  pageRoot: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  navSection: {
    backgroundColor: '#368ec7',
    flex: 25,
    alignSelf: 'stretch'
  },
  searchSection: {
    flex: 75,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
  },
  locationSection: {
    flex: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#276fa3',
    padding: 10,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#205e8c'
  },
  searchParametersSection : {
    flex: 70,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(41,123,184,1)',
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderTopColor: 'rgba(69, 140, 194, 0.7)',
    flexDirection: 'column'
  }
});

export default FlightSearch;
```

Comment: can you post the screenshot with **layout bounds** enabled on yo android phone? this would help debug much faster...

Comment: I am trying to create a minimal example. Will post the code in a few minutes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem within a scrollview, where few images lie horizontally without any space between them. While working on iOS I had no problems however when I switched to Android, those white lines popped out, and they were disappearing at some scroll positions. The hack that I used was adding a `marginRight: -1` (horizontal images).

User won't notice the difference but this way you can resolve the issue.

```
return (
      <ScrollView ref='sr' style={styles.container} horizontal={true}>
        <Image source={im1} style={{height: h, width: 400, resizeMode: 'stretch', marginRight: -1}} />
        <Image source={im2} style={{height: h, width: 400, resizeMode: 'stretch', marginRight: -1}} />
        <Image source={im3} style={{height: h, width: 400, resizeMode: 'stretch', marginRight: -1}} />
        <Image source={im4} style={{height: h, width: 400, resizeMode: 'stretch', marginRight: -1}} />
        <Image source={im5} style={{height: h, width: 400, resizeMode: 'stretch', marginRight: -1}} />
        <Image source={im6} style={{height: h, width: 400, resizeMode: 'stretch', marginRight: -1}} />
      </ScrollView>
    )
```

Comment: I don't think thats what causing it. I am not using a Scrollview for the above

Comment: Same issue appears without a ScrollView.

Comment: Oh. Let me try your fix then

Comment: I set the margin on "locationSection" and "searchParametersSection ". No change

Comment: LocationSection: `marginBottom: -1` right? Dont do anything to searchParametersSection. Let me know the outcome

Comment: If that doesnt help, can you share your code for me to play with?

Comment: Code is up in the question. let me try try setting margin on "LocationSection" only

Comment: Thanks a lot man. That worked. Bu are there any weird side-effects? I thought of doing something like this before but read somewhere that IOS doesnt play nice with negative margins.

Comment: Uhm, alternatively you can wrap them with a view and give a backgroundColor that fits to your design. I don't think giving a -1 margin would ever effect anything wrong. Ive used this hack and works fine on both android and ios

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info

Comment: one issue with this negative margin approach is if your views are fading in and out. The overlapped section will be way more opaque than the rest of it. I'd go with -.1 to minimize the chances of that in this case.