# React Native - Visible parent view despite having no margin in between children views

Tags: css, react-native

I have a screen set up similarly to the codes below

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        navContainer:{
            height:64,
            backgroundColor:'#333333',
            
        },
        rowsContainer:{
            backgroundColor:'red',
            margin:0,
            padding:0,
        },
    });

    return (
        <View>
            <View style={styles.navContainer} />
            <View style={styles.rowsContainer}>
                <ChildrenRow />
                <ChildrenRow />
                <ChildrenRow />
                <ChildrenRow />
                <ChildrenRow />
                <ChildrenRow />
                <ChildrenRow />
                <ChildrenRow />
                <ChildrenRow />
                <ChildrenRow />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

export default App;
```

ChildrenRow

```
const ChildrenRow = () => {

    return (
        <View 
            onLayout={(event) => {
                const {width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
                console.log(`Height/Width= ${height} and ${width}`)
            }}
            style={{
                height:59,
                width:400,
                backgroundColor:'black',
                margin:0,
                padding:0,
            }}/>
    )
}
```

Despite having no margin (nor padding, purposely add in `margin:0, padding:0`), the view with red background is visible on my OPPO F9, in-between the `childrenRows`. The same was observed in a few other devices, and also on some firebase test devices.
[image]

Using Android Studio's layout inspector showed an even worse result, as per the image below
[image]

Also noticed on console, that the heights of some `childrenRows` are weirdly rounded:
[image]

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42565184/react-native-unexplainable-spacea-white-line-between-two-views), but i couldn't use the solution as i will be adding `borderWidth` to each children row and the heights are non-static, which might break the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to **Pixel Grid Snapping**. You can avoid this by using

```
import { PixelRatio } from "react-native";
```

```
const height = PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(8.4)
```

Comment: Using PixelRatio worked, although i have only one physical device to test. Red background is still visible though in Android Studio's LayoutInspector, is this unavoidable?

Comment: you can also [refer](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio#pixel-grid-snapping).

Answer (score 0):

There might be some solutions to your problem. Try messing around with them. Firstly try rounding up row height to 60 (sometimes devices go crazy with odd numbers in UI). Also try setting style of parent component for rows to `flex:1, flexDirection: 'column'` if it doesn't work you can go around this problem by making new component as a black colored mask for background with calculated height and width is you have this set. Make sure it's position is fixed, or absolute, and it's zIndex is lower lesser than rows and greater than backgrounds . This last method is kinda brute force but if it works it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, rounding to 60 and adding another absolute positioned component doesn't manage to hide the red background. Appreciate it though.